# New to Objective C, Creating Custom objects

Tags: objective-c

I am creating some custom objects to practice with.  I have three classes Song, Playlist and Music.  It's easy to instantiate a new Song from my main program, but I was thinking that I should create a method in the Music class to create a new Song and return it to the main program. Here is where I become confused.  After the object is created, where  and when do I release it.  Do I create it and retain it in the Music method and then release it in the main program?  I think that I would need to create another Song object in the main program to receive the returned Song.  I would greatly appreciate some thoughts on this?

Thanks,

gfgruvin

Comment: do you know about ARC? http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

Comment: Using ARC helps you forget about pesky details of that nature :)

Comment: Do you know about iOS 4.x, 3.x? Do you know about people not understanding memory management and writing crap? Be glad he asked and stop downwoting.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic Cocoa design principle is that if you don't create/retain objects using -alloc, -retain, -copy or -mutableCopy, then you're not responsible for releasing them; thus you don't have to (and should not) release them. Memory management in these cases is done like this: the creator class created the object, so it's responsible for releasing it. Since the creator class doesn't know when to release the object, it will simply -autorelease it. In your case, this will be done like this (supposed your Song class has some kind of a Title property):

```
@implementation Music

+ (Song *) songWithTitle:(NSString *)title
{
    Song *s = [[[Song alloc] init] autorelease]; // autorelease make our conscience happy
    s.title = title;
    return s;
}

@end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Beyond the scope of the OP's original question but that looks like an awfully rigid design. What happens if I create a subclass of `Song` and want that returned instead?

Comment: @JonathanSterling This would not work as the example want's a new `Song` from within the `Music` class. I was thinking more about DI/abstract factories.

Comment: Wtf? If the class is Music, and you want to return a Song, you cannot possibly use self! (I know if it was the Song class I should have used self, obviously. But since OP explicitly stated he wants a Song using a Music class, I wrote it as per his question...)

Comment: @H2CO3 I'm not sure the "wtf?" is quite required? Jonathan obviously misread the question with his response, but I stand by my original comment.

Comment: You did, but he shouldn't be blaspheming the answer just because he overlooked it...

Comment: @H2CO3 Surely the best thing to do is to actually address your replies at the commenter and then they will be notified of your response and may well decide to remove their comment.

Comment: Oh dear. My apologies! It's really much more idiomatic to have this method on `Song` rather than `Music`, so I totally overlooked it. And the question was more about memory management (the OP's questionable architecture is tangential). Please ignore my comment and accept my apologies for the confusion!

Comment: No problem! :) I knew OP's architecture was not perfect, but I wanted to answer him nevertheless.